# Magento - Add column to END of table in Custom Module (without copying over ALL columns)

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I've made a simple module which has the option to put in an "Edit" action column in **Catalog > Manage Categories > [Catalog Products tab]**. The code works fine, however, it places the new column at the **beginning** of the table and I want it at the ***end*** of the table (for aesthetics).

Here's the rewrite (Product.php):

```
class [Company]_[Namespace]_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product 
{
protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
                    'width' => '50px',
                    'type' => 'action',
                    'getter' => 'getId',
                    'actions' => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                            'url' => array(
                                'base'=>'*/catalog_product/edit',
                                'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                            ),
                            'field' => 'id'
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter' => false,
                    'sortable' => false,
                    'index' => 'stores',
            ));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
}
```

If I move `return parent::_prepareColumns();` above the new column, then the new column does not show at all.

So my question, again, is how do I move this new column to the **END** of the table *without* copying all the columns into the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();
    $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                        'url' => array(
                            'base'=>'*/catalog_product/edit',
                            'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                        ),
                        'field' => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
        ));
    return $this;
}
```

There's also `addColumnsOrder` function but it will make no sense here as you are adding column to the very end.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I figured out the answer right as you posted. I'll give you the credit. My issue, of course, was I needed to declare `parent::_prepareColumns();` first, then call it after. You can definitely have the credit here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is using `addColumnAfter`. Suppose, the last column in the existing grid is named `xyz`. Now, to add a new column named `myNewColumn` to the end of the grid, i.e. after column `xyz`:

```
protected function _prepareColumns(){
    $this->addColumnAfter('myNewColumn', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('My New Column'),
        'index'  => 'myNewColumn'
    ),'xyz');
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```